# Replace All NULL Values in my Query [MYSQL]

Tags: mysql

Currently I am using a query which has a right join between 2 tables `users` [user_id, username] and `user_comments` [user_id, user_comments]. There is a possibility that when doing the right join on `user_comments` that the returned values will have some `NULLs` within the user_id column. 
How can I replace all the `NULL` values within the column `user_id` with `Unknown`

Comment: Have you seen the `COALESCE()` method?

Comment: What is the datatype of user_id?

Comment: its a varchar @MartinSmith

Answer (score 0):

You could try COALESCE(user_id, 'Unknown'). Less costly than ISNULL and will automatically return the string unknown if user_id is null

Baptiste

Comment: I actually used the `IFNULL` `COALESCE` only returns one value when I may have several

Comment: could you copy paste your query ?